# mapStateToProps connect must return a plain object

Tags: react-redux

I am trying to open a modal using Redux, however, I get the error:

**mapStateToProps() in Connect(ModalRoot) must return a plain object. Instead recieved indefined.**

Here is my Modal componenet:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import InformationModal from './InformationModal.js';

const MODAL_COMPONENTS = {
  SHOW_INFORMATION: InformationModal,
  // ADD_ACHIEVEMENT: AddAchievementModal,
  // SHOW_ERROR: ErrorModal,

  /* other modals */
};

const ModalRoot = ({ modalType, modalProps }) => {
  if (!modalType) {
    return <span />; // after React v15 you can return null here
  }

  const SpecificModal = MODAL_COMPONENTS[modalType];
  return <SpecificModal {...modalProps} />;
};

export default connect(state => state.modal)(ModalRoot);
```

My information modal:

```
export default class InformationModal extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <span>
        <ModalWrapper onRequestClose={this.props.onClose} contentLabel={title}>
          <Text>hello</Text>
        </ModalWrapper>
      </span>
    );
  }
}
```

And my modal Wrapper:

```
class ModalExample extends Component {
  state = {
    modalVisible: false,
  };

  setModalVisible(visible) {
    this.setState({ modalVisible: visible });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ marginTop: 22 }}>
        <Modal
          animationType={'slide'}
          transparent={false}
          visible={this.state.modalVisible}
          onRequestClose={() => {
            alert('Modal has been closed.');
          }}>
          {this.props.children}
        </Modal>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Anyone know why I get this error?

Answer (score 2):

In this function:

```
export default connect(state => state.modal)(ModalRoot);
```

The `state.modal` is undefined and mapStateToProps requires you to return an Object

Try this:

```
export default connect(state => state.modal || {})(ModalRoot);
```